# Arraylist indexOf and lastIndexOf of substring

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How can I get the index of a substring in an arraylist.

E.g. Arraylist with these entries:

```
[60EBFF0003CF030501CF0304, 60EBFF000104FF210D0301A5, 60EBFF0002020301F9100401, 60EBFF0003CF030501CF0304, 60EBFF000104FF210D0301A5]
```

`60EBFF0001` is always the same, the rest of the string is variable.

`indexOf("60EBFF0001") returns -1` and `lastIndexOf("60EBFF0001")` also returns -1, but I need 1 and 3.

Because I have to delete everything before index 1 and after index 3.

Comment: Creating a class and overriding the `equals` and `hashCode` method might help you here instead of working with plain `String`'s

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: 60EBFF0001 is a substring of an entry

Answer (score 1):

When `list` is your ArrayList instance you can use the following Java 8 code to determine first and last index of elements which contain a particular substring:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .filter(i -> list.get(i).contains("60EBFF0001"))
        .summaryStatistics();
if (stats.getCount() > 0) {
    System.out.println("First index: " + stats.getMin());
    System.out.println("Last index: " + stats.getMax());
} else {
    System.out.println("No match");
}
```

By the way, the last index of an element that contains `60EBFF0001` is not 3 but 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably extend `ArrayList` with something of your own like:

```
private class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {
    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        int foundAtIndex = -1;

        for (int index = 0; index < size(); index++) {
            if (get(index).contains(((String) o))) {
                foundAtIndex = index;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundAtIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        int foundAtIndex = -1;

        for (int index = size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            if (get(index).contains(((String) o))) {
                foundAtIndex = index;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundAtIndex;
    }
}
```